# How to include using declaratives with CodeDomProvider in c#?

Tags: c#, codedom

I want to compile several .cs-files to an executable program.
My CodeDomProvider doesn't find the using declaratives that I wrote into the .cs-files. Especially the followings error Messages are created:

> -The type- or namespace 'CodeDom' in the namespace 'System' is not available.
>   -The type- or namespace 'Windows' in the namespace 'System' is not available.
>   -The type- or namespace 'Stack' could not be found.

From this function, I'm calling the CodeDomProvider:

```
    private CompileParserSolution()
    {
        List<string> cSharpFiles = new List<string>();

        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(_inData.ProjectDir, @"NCParser\NCParser"));

        foreach (FileInfo f in dir.GetFiles("*.cs"))
        {
            cSharpFiles.Add(Path.Combine(dir.FullName, f.Name));
        }

        CodeDomProvider provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");

        CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
        cp.GenerateExecutable = true;
        cp.OutputAssembly = "Parser_TEST.exe";
        cp.GenerateInMemory = true;
        cp.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Linq.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Path.Combine(_inData.ProjectDir, @"NCParser\NCParser", @"QUT.ShiftReduceParser.dll"));

        CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(cp, cSharpFiles.ToArray());
    }
```

My question is, how can I include the `System.CodeDom`, `System.Windows` and the `System.Collections.Stack` librarys into the project to compile.

With the command:

```
        cs.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.CodeDom.dll");
        ...
```

it doesn't work!

Comment: cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assemblies and namespaces don't correspond to each other 1:1. To find in which assembly a certain type is, look at its MSDN documentation.

- There is no System.CodeDom.dll, a lot of the CodeDOM types are in the System.dll, which you didn't reference.
- `Stack<T>` is likewise in System.dll.
- WPF is spread over several assemblies, the basic types are in PresentationFramework.dll.

Referencing these assemblies will likely fix your issue.